# Moq : FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime'

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to learn Moq, and unit testing and i've got an error i don't understand when trying to use Moq.

The code below is pretty much copy-pasted from https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart. I'm using it because the error also occurs on the main project i am working on and i just want to limit and potential errors i've caused with my newbishness.

System.Runtime has been downloaded, and it's referenced.

Edit: Also i've tried version 4.0.0 and the error is still there.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Proje.Controllers;
using Proje.Models;
using Proje.DAL;
using Moq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Runtime;


namespace Proje.UnitTests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class BaseControllerTests
    {
        public interface IFoo
        {
            Bar Bar { get; set; }
            string Name { get; set; }
            int Value { get; set; }
            bool DoSomething(string value);
            bool DoSomething(int number, string value);
            string DoSomethingStringy(string value);
            bool TryParse(string value, out string outputValue);
            bool Submit(ref Bar bar);
            int GetCount();
            bool Add(int value);
        }

        public class Bar
        {
            public virtual Baz Baz { get; set; }
            public virtual bool Submit() { return false; }
        }

        public class Baz
        {
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestTest() {

            var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
            mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
            //Assert some stuff
        }
```

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.10.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reflection" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.RegularExpressions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Linq" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.4.0" newVersion="1.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="8fb06cb64d019a17" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.8.1.0" newVersion="2.8.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Edit: Log

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/20/2018 @ 7:49:44 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\testhost.x86.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/NAME/source/repos/Proj/Proj.UnitTests/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Tests_16537946
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\NAME\source\repos\Proj\Proj.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Proj.UnitTests.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.1.2.0 redirected to 4.1.2.0.
LOG: ProcessorArchitecture is locked to MSIL.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/NAME/source/repos/Proj/Proj.UnitTests/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/NAME/source/repos/Proj/Proj.UnitTests/bin/Debug/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/NAME/source/repos/Proj/Proj.UnitTests/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/NAME/source/repos/Proj/Proj.UnitTests/bin/Debug/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: please run `fuslogvw` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer, turn on logging and add information about failed assembly bind, together with attempted locations

Comment: @ironstone13 Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, can you please now change your binding redirect `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />` and replace `4.1.2.0` with the version `"4.3.0"` that you are using in packages?

Comment: Boom! Thanks, all working now. I tried that before but used 4.3.0.0 instead of 4.3.0. Please leave your comment as an answer so i can mark it for you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, as we discovered together with *@loveforfire33* during investigation using `fuslogvw` the issue was in versioning.

Packages.config used version `4.3.0`
`<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />`

However, binding redirect in app.config was configured for version `4.1.2.0`

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Changing binding redirect upper limit version and new version to `4.3.0` solved the issue.